# Why are my dialogs not draggable in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, dialog, draggable

I've created a dialog in jQuery but they are not draggable even though i've set 'draggable: true'. Can anyone see what's wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="lessonDetails">
    <a href="#popUpLink" class="popUpLink">Lesson Details</a>
    <div class="popUpDialog" title="Lesson Details">
       <p>'.$l['name'].'</p>
       <p><a href="">Resources and Objectives</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.popUpLink').each(function()
{
    $divDialog = $(this).next('.popUpDialog');
    $.data(this, 'dialog', $divDialog.dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: $divDialog.attr('title')
        //draggable: true   
    }));
}).click(function()
{
    $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: do you have an error message? do you load jQuery UI? your draggable line is commented out. Activate it and put a comma after the previous line.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Wzya4/

Comment: @jgauffin thats because the jQuery UI library on jsfiddle is the complete library ...

Comment: Can you show us your test page somewhere?

Comment: No error messages or anything :s

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the `draggable:true` as its [the default value](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-draggable) ..

But you do need to include 2 additional libraries to make `draggable` work:

```
<script src="pathto/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="pathto/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

Have a look at the dependencies section [on the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

When you [download the jQuery UI Libraries](http://jqueryui.com/download) you have to select which "modules" you require - your need to select the ones above or better still reference the complete jQuery UI library [using Googles CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI)

Comment: where do you read about those dependencies? I have used the `draggable` option and never used those two scripts before.

Comment: @YanickRochon have a look at the link i included - when you download the jQuery UI library you pick which libraries you use - maybe you selected all - or use Googles CDN ?

Comment: These are my two dependancies:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hmmmmmmm, this is bugging me so bad! Do you know where the ajax.googleapis link is for the two dependencies in your answer are?

Comment: the googleapis link you posted is the complete library so it should work

Answer (score 0):

Youve missed a comma after:

```
title: $divDialog.attr('title')
```

You could have probably seen this in a javascript console or debugger

Comment: It should be draggable per default

Comment: that was my error when editing the code here when I was posting the question. My bad